# How do i make a batch file with a time and date as a name?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file that makes backups of a specific folder and so i want the date and time as a name

code::

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do md "%%a.%%b.%%c"

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do md "%%a_%%b_%%c"

md "(%date%%time%)"
```

This makes two separate folders where i only want one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
md "%date:/=-%-%time::=-%"
```

Comment: Thanks man, Is it possable to say for example "(05/06/12)at(12.06)"

Comment: slashes `/`  are not allowed in file names.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more robust and reliable method - XP Pro and higher:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

MD "%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to limit the time to two factors like "(05/06/12)at(12.06)" if its possible thanks :)

Comment: `/` is an illegal filename character.